# How to write shell script to login to particular server based on environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can someone help me?

I need to write a shell script that will login to 3 servers and check if 2 or more mentioned processes are running if we grep with the environment

Scenario:

I have 3 Environments (Dev, Staging, Prod) and 3 servers (serv01, serv02, serv03) where 3 processes (module01, module02, module03) will run.

I need to check if these 3 modules are running in all the environments using bash script.

Ex: In serv01, i need to check like below

```
ps -aux | grep Dev

Output: user1 12321 .8  0.0  2449   Mar04  21:18 /opt/DEV/Module01 --port 8087 
        user1 12321 .8  0.0  2449   Mar04  21:18 /opt/DEV/Module02 --port 8088
        user1 12321 .8  0.0  2449   Mar04  21:18 /opt/DEV/Module03 --port 8089
```

In similar way i need to check other environments Staging and Prod for serv02 and serv03 .

Is it possible to write shell script

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java (not shell but is working) with the library Process and ProcessBuilder to read and write into the console !

This is an example :

```
  public static Process ExecuteCommand(String command) { 
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(); //process builder instance
    pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c", command); //select the terminal and the command input
    try {
        Process myProcess = pb.start(); //start process and return it for the output
        return myProcess;
    }catch (IOException er){
        System.out.println("Error on executing the process , err"+er.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

And to read you can use:

```
    public static List ReadProcessOutput(Process processToRead){ 
    List<String> items = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processToRead.getInputStream())); //the process output is going to be the input for the buffer
    String line = null;
    try{
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //for each line i save the response into a List
            items.add(line); //add the line to the 
        }
    }catch(IOException er){
        System.out.println("Error: "+er.toString());
    }
    return items; //return the list , in each item you have a console line output
}
```

You need to pass to the method ExecuteCommand("ps -aux | grep Dev")
and if you don't find any output it means your modules are not working.

Code on the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List lines = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Starting");
    lines = ReadProcessOutput(ExecuteCommand("ps -aux | grep Dev"));

    //implement the checks
    for (String line : lines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```